# Is it possible to upload directly without touching my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is it possible to use carrier wave to upload directly to amazon's S3 without using my server?

What i mean is, I don't want the images first going to my ec2 instance, and then uploaded to s3.  I believe there is a way to upload directly to S3 to save my server's resources from having to process/stream the file.

I am just looking into carierwave, does it support nice html5 uploads where the user can just drag and drop the file on the web page?

Comment: CarrierWave is more focused on the actual server side parts of file uploads in Rails (or ruby in general). It won't give you anything if you want to do a direct upload with ajax that bypasses your rails server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload directly to S3 from the browser you must do it with Javascript.
Heroku provides a nice tutorial : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

Once uploaded, you can pass the finale S3 public URL of the image in a hidden field and download it server-side with carrierwave for further manipulation (resizing, ...)